# Stripping string from lines in text file and reading columns into dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, file-io

I've been struggling a bit with getting my input file into the right format for my algorithm.

I want to read this text file:

```
1 -> 7,8
11 -> 1,19
219 -> 1,9,8
```

Into this dictionary:

```
{ 1: [7, 8], 11: [1, 19], 219: [1, 9, 8]}
```

I've tried this code:

```
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.write(f.read().replace("->", " "))
    f.close()

d = {}
with open("file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[key] = val
```

But with this code it get's stuck on the fact that there are more than 2 arguments in the second column. How can make a list out of the elements in the second column and use that list as the value for each key?

Comment: Why do you use `f.write(...)` etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no need to do that pre-processing step to remove the `'->'`**. Simply use:

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        left,right = line.split('->')
        d[int(left)] = [int(v) for v in right.split(',')]
```

You can even use *dictionary comprehension* and make it a one-liner:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    d = {int(left) : [int(v) for v in right.split(',')]
             for left,right in (line.split('->') for line in file)
        }
```

This gives:

```
>>> d
{1: [7, 8], 11: [1, 19], 219: [1, 9, 8]}
```

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: yes, writing two answers concurrently is not a good idea..

Comment: One could argue that `[int(v) for v in right.split(',')]` would be a tad more pythonic than `list(map(int,right.split(',')))`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I get a ValueError with both of the above codes:
line 27, in <module>
    left,right = line.split('->')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
EDIT: It's probably because there are lines in the file which only have one value for the key.

Comment: @DavidK11: but you probably already rewrite your file with the algorithm you wrote yourself. You need to remove the lines you inserted yourself: only lines with arrows should be allowed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I double checked if that's the problem by re-copying the original file. But I think the issue is that there are lines in the file which only have one value for the key.

Comment: No, the unpacking only is done for splitting on the `->` so it means there is at least one line without `->`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yes you were right, there was an empty line at the end of the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nest a generator expression with `str.split` in a dictionary comprehension, converting the key to an integer and mapping the value to integers:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    result = {int(k):list(map(int, v.split(','))) for k,v in (line.split(' -> ') for line in f)}
```

Comment: `v` is a string: `'1,9,8'`. `list(map(int,'1,9,8'))` will crash...: it will iterate over the chars thus only parsing 1-digit numbers, and crash on the comma.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - Sorry, didn't notice the commas; fixed.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You could also get the lists of integers with `list(ast.literal_eval(v))`.